# AutoHotkey, use the mac keyboard on the win system to integrate the command button with control and option

Tags: autohotkey

[autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) is an application program that can exchange key settings in WIN system.

I want to implement two functions:

1. Copy and paste function: map win's `control+c` and `+v` to `command+d` (Replace `control` with `command`)
2. Switch window function: map `option+tab` to `command+d` (Replace `option` with `command`)

---

1. Copy and paste can be achieved through the following script:

`LControl::LWin LWin::LControl RControl::RWin RWin::RControl`

[image]

2. But switching windows can’t be achieved. It seems that there will be a priority problem. Suppose I stay in chrome, even if I map successfully(`option+tab` to `command+d`), clicking `command+d` under chrome will trigger the page switching of chrome, rather than switching the sorting display of the application.

Comment: You don't want BOTH of those functions as command+d, do you?

Comment: @TimRoberts What I mean is that I want to click `command+d` to switch the display of the top layer of the application on the screen. But this part cannot be realized.

Comment: @TimRoberts Sorry I fixed my problem 2. It is `option+tab` not `control+tab`